# Visual Studio conditional compilation code block greyed out with no intellisense or color formatting

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

I have a C# project which targets net48 and netcore20. I see that the code files where there is a conditional compilation with regards to the net framework, the code is greyed out - no IntelliSense or color formatting to help with the code development. Is there a setting to enable this?

Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise Edition

Comment: Change the active build configuration to match that specified in the [Conditional(“xxxxx”)]

Comment: Hi @MickyD: I could see only Release/Debug configurations in the Build->Configuration Manager.

Comment: You need to know what preprocessor symbols are checked for those conditional code blocks. Then have suitable build configurations that set those symbols.

Comment: Is Resharper installed? Then use the left dropdown box above the code window to change the configuration.